# Shortening long and repetitive equations in Python

Tags: python, equation

I have this long equation

```
def equation(x, s, z, m, p1, f1, g1, e1, p2, f2, g2, e2, p3, f3, g3, e3, p4, f4, g4, e4, p5, f5, g5, e5,
                  p6, f6, g6, e6, p7, f7, g7, e7):
    return float(s) + (float(z) / pow(x, float(m))) + (float(p1) * (1 + float(e1) * (x - float(f1))) / (
    pow((x - float(f1)), 2) + pow((float(g1) / 2), 2)) + float(p2) * (1 + float(e2) * (x - float(f2))) / (
    pow((x - float(f2)), 2) + pow((float(g2) / 2), 2)) + float(p3) * (1 + float(e3) * (x - float(f3))) / (
    pow((x - float(f3)), 2) + pow((float(g3) / 2), 2)) + float(p4) * (1 + float(e4) * (x - float(f4))) / (
    pow((x - float(f4)), 2) + pow((float(g4) / 2), 2)) + float(p5) * (1 + float(e5) * (x - float(f5))) / (
    pow((x - float(f5)), 2) + pow((float(g5) / 2), 2)) + float(p6) * (1 + float(e6) * (x - float(f6))) / (
    pow((x - float(f6)), 2) + pow((float(g6) / 2), 2)) + float(p7) * (1 + float(e7) * (x - float(f7))) / (
    pow((x - float(f7)), 2) + pow((float(g7) / 2), 2)))
```

As you can see everything, but the beginning and numbers is the same, is there any way to shorten that with a loop or something else? I thought about list comprehension, but I have no clue how to write it in this example.

Cheers!

Comment: When shortening big expressions like this, it's helpful to find repetitive parts and extract them into functions. When you do this, the code gets shorter and it becomes easier to think of ways to shorten it further. E.g. make a function that calculates `pow((x - float(something)), 2)`

Comment: Then look at converting f1, f2, f3 etc into a list, which you can reference with `f[0]`, `f[1]`, `f[2]` etc.

Comment: Patterns are a great hint, but be careful of choosing the wrong abstraction. If those expressions conceptually mean something, then *that* should be a function. Arbitrarily creating a `def func1(x, y): return (x + 1) / 3 + sqrt(x**2 + y**2) / max(x, y + 6)` isn't really reducing complexity. Instead, `def distance(x, y): return sqrt(x**2 + y**2)` is a better way to break things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for this case:

```
def equation(x, s, z, m, p1, f1, g1, e1, p2, f2, g2, e2, p3, f3, g3, e3, p4, f4, g4, e4, p5, f5, g5, e5,
                  p6, f6, g6, e6, p7, f7, g7, e7):
    plist = [[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7],
             [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7],
             [g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7],
             [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7]]

    result = s + (z / pow(x, m))
    for i in range(0, 7):
        result += plist[0][i] * (1 + plist[3][i] * (x - plist[1][i])) / \
                  (pow((x - plist[1][i]), 2) + pow((plist[2][i] / 2), 2))
    return result
```

The reason behind keeping all parameters is that I need them later for using with `lmfit` module, which requires all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
def equation(x, s, z, m, es, fs, gs, ps):
    something = sum(
        p * (1 + e * (x - f)) / (pow(x - f, 2) + pow(g / 2, 2))
        for e, f, g, p in zip(es, fs, gs, ps)
    )
    return s + z / pow(x, m) + something
```

Where:

```
es = [e1, e2, ...]
fs = [f1, f2, ...]
gs = ...
ps = ...
```

You don't really need to specify `float` type conversions explicitly since python does that "automatically".

Answer (score 1):

Here is variant without changing parameters order.

```
def equation2(x, s, z, m, *params):
    def subeq(x, p, f, g, e):
        return (float(p) * (1 + float(e) * (x - float(f))) / 
                (pow((x - float(f)), 2) + pow((float(g) / 2), 2)))
    return (float(s) + (float(z) / pow(x, float(m))) +
            sum(subeq(x, *pfge) for pfge in zip(*([iter(params)]*4))))
```

not great readability, but it just splits all parameters after x,s,z,m to groups by four and calculate sum of repeated expression